# Tag badges display badge instead of tag on the earned badges tab

Tags: bug, tag-badges

If I go to Badges then select the [earned tab](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=earned) then scroll down to tag badges, I see I have earned a silver badge in the silver badge tag :

[image: screenshot showing I earned a badge in the Silver Badge tag]

Looks like the tag badges are displayed as aggregates too, since I have more than two of them. This might be by design, however.

Comment: Probably it has the same i18n property as in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/276/java?userid=1064325), for example